# Highlight the clicked event in Alam kanak Week View Library

Tags: android, material-design, android-library

i am using compile  **'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'** library in my app.i would like to highlight the selected EmptyView when clicked for the first time. i did override onEmptyViewClicked(Calendar time) of library but by calling super.getView().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d); it changes the back ground of whole View instead of only empty View. how to Change the Color of empty View when clicked (Or HighLight it)? how to Achieve that?

Here is what i am doing now.

```
   @Override
public void onEmptyViewClicked(Calendar time) {

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

    getView().setBackground(gd);




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after spending time for searching i got to know that there is already an answer on github but its not merged with the master branch. i wanted to give range to calendar's horizontal scroll plus highlight the empty event on first tap. user can add event on second tap.clone this repo in to ur project/ add as module. **https://github.com/mrwhite1/WeekViewLibrary** 
now you can set the scroll range using

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
    mWeekView.setMinDate(cal);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DATE,21);

    mWeekView.setMaxDate(c);
```

for highlighting (and then adding) event add,

```
   mWeekView.setEmptyViewClickListener(this);

    // Set AddEvent Click Listener
    mWeekView.setAddEventClickListener(this);

    @Override
public void onEmptyViewClicked(Calendar time, Calendar tempTime, boolean clickedTwice) {

 //empty event clicked for the first time
}


@Override
public void onAddEventClicked(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime) {

   // set your logic to add event (second tap)

}
```